# Rails Time Column Not Respecting Minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a `Time` column on one of my models in Rails 6. I'm having an issue with the time I have saved in the database not matching the result of `strftime`. Here is my `byebug` output:

```
(byebug) record.end
Fri, 31 Dec 1999 18:00:00 CST -06:00
(byebug) record.end.strftime("%I:%m %P")
"06:12 pm"
```

As you'll see, the minutes aren't respected unless I call `strftime`. How can I fix this? I want the minutes to be calculated in `record.end` so that I can use the column for calculations. Currently, everything is 12 minutes off.

Here is the migration I made to make this a `Time` column. The column was initially a `DateTime`.

```
class ChangeStartAndEndColumnTypesOnTimeRecord < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    change_column :time_records, :start, :time
    change_column :time_records, :end, :time
  end
end
```

Comment: Which database are you using? mysql?

Comment: @Mshka PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2):

A common mistake, `%m` gives the month. You need to use `%M` for minutes.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use `DateTime` as the column type.

your code `record.end` actually is not a String, but a Integer (unix timestamp). if you want only the `minutes` part, you can get it via:

```
# only get minutes
record.end.strftime("%M")

# get year, month, day , hour, minutes...
record.end.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

=> 2021-04-25 08:14:53
```

If you really don't like to call `strftime` every time when you need the 'minutes', you can define a global method in Rails, such as

( the code below is not tested in production environment, just a explain purpose )

```
# in config/initializers/datetime.rb or something
class DateTime
  def to_s
    this.strftime('%M')  # this will only output the minutes 
  end
end
```

Comment: You are also mixing it up. You've got it right when formatting the whole date but wrong when accessing the minutes. It needs to be %M, upper case.

Comment: @eweb oh yeah, you are right, I corrected it.